# Errors being logged from Azure Worker Roles

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-worker-roles

I have several Azure (Classic) Cloud Service worker roles, with VM Size Extra small (1 core, 768 MB). I'm noticing frequent errors being logged (several times a day) to application insights.  The errors seem to be from the Windows system itself whilst attempting to defrag drives. These errors don't seem to be of any consequence other than they're filling up logs unnecessarily.  I'd like to get rid of them anyhow. Here's the raw XML for the errors logged...

```
<Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'>
    <System>
        <Provider Name='Microsoft-Windows-Defrag'/>
        <EventID Qualifiers='32768'>257</EventID>
        <Level>2</Level>
        <Task>0</Task>
        <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime='2019-03-29T04:23:21.000000000Z'/>
        <EventRecordID>623</EventRecordID>
        <Channel>Application</Channel>
        <Computer>prod0</Computer>
        <Security/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data>(C:)</Data>
        <Data>Neither Slab Consolidation nor Slab Analysis will run if slabs are less than 8 MB. (0x8900002D)</Data>
        <Binary>2D0000896303000094010000AE0100002236B942D9B1BD381B0700000000000000000000</Binary>
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

and...

```
<Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'>
    <System>
        <Provider Name='Microsoft-Windows-Defrag'/>
        <EventID Qualifiers='32768'>257</EventID>
        <Level>2</Level>
        <Task>0</Task>
        <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime='2019-03-29T04:23:20.000000000Z'/>
        <EventRecordID>622</EventRecordID>
        <Channel>Application</Channel>
        <Computer>prod0</Computer>
        <Security/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data>SYSTEM</Data>
        <Data>This operation is not supported on this filesystem. (0x89000020)</Data>
        <Binary>00000000A40500005105000000000000629468641336AAB85B55B1B5B038000000000000</Binary>
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

There's also another with the message...

> The Collect Procedure for the "D:\Windows\System32\winspool.drv"
>   service in DLL "Spooler" generated an exception or returned an invalid
>   status. The performance data returned by the counter DLL will not be
>   returned in the Perf Data Block. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the
>   Data section contains the exception code or status code.

and operation_SyntheticSource: AzureDiag_WEL

Has anyone else encountered these errors and did you have a resolution for them?

Comment: As far as I know that the extra small is not recommended to be used in production but any way,  
are the above records are Errors, warnings or informational records, if they are not errors then you I think you can customize the logs that get ingested to the appinsights 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/vs-azure-tools-diagnostics-for-cloud-services-and-virtual-machines?view=vs-2017

Comment: @Mohammad It may not be recommended, but there's a huge leap in price between small and the next up the scale.  My application is just performing background processing, like sending emails and scheduled tasks. In a previous incarnation (before the cloud) it ran as a windows service.  It doesn't really processing power, I could definitely do with more memory, 800MB isn't much when the OS takes half of that.